# Rails Date Range Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, activerecord, range

I have had a look through some previous questions on this topic but none seem to relate to what I am trying to do,

I have a model called Season that has an  ID,Name, Start Date, End Date.

So lets say I have 2 records:

```
1, Season 1, 02-01-2014, 01-01-2015 
2, Season 2, 02-01-2015, 01-01-2016
```

I would like to be able to find which season a date range falls in by providing the date. I suspect I need to create a method but some pointers on what that code should look like would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your date is in the variable `my_date`, you should be able to get the seasons that contain is as follows:

```
Season.where(Season.arel_table[:start_date].lt(my_date))
      .where(Season.arel_table[:end_date].gteq(my_date))
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work but the object it returns is not quite what i was expecting, I get a `<Season::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x614d708>` object but it does not have any of the values I am expecting, I cant query its ID or anything. What object should this return and how to I work with it?

Comment: I have read up on ActiveRecord Relations and I have now got it working, thank you for your help.